# fbx export destroys the bone direction

Tags: armature, export, import, .fbx

When I try to export the model as fbx file, the bone structure is destroyed.

I've checked not to add leaf bone when importing/exporting the file.

It is suppposed to look like this.
[image]

After I export/import it as a fbx file, it turns out as below.
[image]

If you have any suggestions please comment.
I will also attach the file here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7szzi3teq2m1b99/neko%E5%AE%8C%E6%88%90%E7%89%88_%E4%BF%AE%E6%AD%A3%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF_20230528.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If I display all the bone layers, and export only the armature object, the imported armature doesn't seem broken:

[image: armatures comparison]

It has all the bones present in the original, they seem in the same place, aside from  `mixamorig:HeadTop_End`, but it doesn't seem to impact the mesh deformation anyway, so maybe nothing to worry about:

[image: head top bones]

The only real difference is the presence of "leaf bones" with the `_end` suffix at the end of their names, like these:

[image: leaf bones]

Like the `mixamorig:HeadTop_End` which I suppose was generated by mixamo, these "leaf bones" are generated by Blender's FBX exporter:

[image: leaf bones]

These bones are harmelss, their only purposes is to define the position of the tail of a bone. It's more of a display conveninence for when you export a skeleton made out of bones to a software that uses "joints" instead of bones. Joints only have one point of reference, unlike bones which have two (heads and tails). Joints have their end point where their child is and therefore "no head point" when a joint have no child, while bones have an indepentend tail, so you can chose to export an extra bone (called a leaf) when a bone is at the end of a chain so that a joint-based skeleton system (like Maya) would still know where the bone tails are.

It is completely facultative, you can disable it from the exporter, and you can also choose to ignore leaf bones when importing:

[image: don't import]

More about it:

[Maya Help | Joints and bones | Autodesk](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-1B59334F-2605-44C3-B584-A55B239A2CBE)

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation, now I understand.